# XMLOutPutter and FileWriter not working with context path

Tags: java, xml, servlets

Hello I have a trouble figureing out why I can't use the context path to write to an xml file, but can use it to get my xml document. I'm trying to add content to an existing xml file.

In my servlet I use this simple line to get the path of the xml file.

```
URL path = getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/workinfo.xml");
```

I then instantiate an object, which is also required in my method doing the xml work. Then calling the method.

```
    WorktoXML workto = new WorktoXML();
    workto.uploadToXML(works, path);
```

Below is my method which is inside my class WorktoXML, which I'm calling from my servlet.

```
 public void uploadToXML(work workss, URL path) throws JDOMException,
                IOException {

        work work = workss;

        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();

        Document document = saxBuilder.build(path.toString());

        Element root = document.getRootElement();

        List<Element> list = root.getChildren("works");
        String id = Integer.toString(list.size());
        Element works = new Element("works");

        works.setAttribute(new Attribute("id", id));
        works.addContent(new Element("username").setText(work.getUsername()));
        works.addContent(new Element("subject").setText(work.getSubject()));
        works.addContent(new Element("body").setText(work.getBody()));
        works.addContent(new Element("imageurl").setText(work.getImagepath()));

        document.getRootElement().addContent(works);   
        XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();    
        xmlOutput.output(document, System.out);
        xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());

        //This is where it goes wrong.
        xmlOutput.output(document,new FileWriter(path.toString())));
    }
```

Running the above results in a java.io.FileNotFoundException:
It works if I just use the absolute path of the xml file, but that is not ideal.

Any help is appreciated. Please tell me if I can give more info about my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .war file is immutable, for security reasons.

Sure, a container may unpack the .war file for better performance, but the unpacked files *should never be updated*. Well, except when upgrading the webapp with a new .war file, or course.

Any uploaded file must be stored elsewhere, outside the .war file, and outside the exploded/unpacked .war directory structure.

Where you store it is up to you. In a directory, in a database, some other location?

If you want your webapp to come with a default resource, but allow a custom resource to be uploaded, store the custom resource in location of your choice. When later querying for the resource, first check if a custom file exists. If not, then you get the default resource like you did, and return that.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. I made it work now thanks to you!